# the maximum number of blocks that will fit inside the box?

Tags: geometry

> What is the maximum number of
>   rectangular blocks, each with
>   dimensions 12 centimeters by 6
>   centimeters by 4 centimeters, that
>   will fi t inside rectangular Box X ?
>   The inside dimensions of Box X are 60
>   centimeters by 30 centimeters by 20
>   centimeters.

Comment: @Hans If the box is resting on a side that is 30 cm by 20 cm, then 30/6,20/4 × = 5 × 5 = 25 blocks will fi t on the bottom layer. In this case, the height of the box is 60 cm and 60/12 = 5 layers will fi t inside the box.

Comment: @prem shekhar:  This is what I've suggested in my answer below, so I guess I don't see where you're having trouble.  Let me repeat from below that if you've completely filled the box, then you've used the maximum number of blocks!

Comment: @Hans If the box is resting
on a side that is 60 cm by 30 cm, then
60/12 , 30/6
× = 5 × 5 = 25 blocks will fi t on the
bottom layer. In this case, the height of the
box is 20 cm and
20/4
= 5 layers will fi t
inside the box.

Comment: @Hans  ya ya..in this way in any way we will get 25*5=125

Comment: @Hans i was facing problem that.......I thought that there can be multiple way to assemble so how can i get to know in which way maximum will fit........Now i am clear  Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture!

Pick a bottom for the box, and try to fill that bottom completely.  If you can stack the pattern that fills the bottom completely a number of times that evenly divides the height, you've completely filled the box.  If you have no leftover space, you've certainly used the maximum number of blocks.

**Hint**:  You can fill the box in your problem completely.

Here's a similar example.  Say I had $1 \times 2 \times 3$ blocks and a $2 \times 4 \times 6$ box.  Then along the bottom ($2\times4$) of the box, I need to decide if I want the bottom of the blocks to be $1\times2$, $2\times3$, or $1\times3$.  I can fill the bottom of the box with 4 blocks by choosing $1\times2$ bottoms.  By stacking this pattern twice, I've filled the entire box!